# Liferay Audience Targeting

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am new to Liferay and I deploy Liferay Audience Targeting -7.lpkg in deploy folder and restart my server still it's not showing in Liferay DXP

Then I check in GOGO Shell there Liferay Audience targeting module is showing but in Resolved state but when using diag on that module it's showing No resolution report for the bundle. Can't able to get where a problem is.[GOGO Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn6xb.png)

Comment: I have similar issue.

Comment: I assume you are using the EE edition? In that case did you patch your EE server to the right level for audiencing targetting?

Answer (score 0):

I am not using GOGO Shell. However, I had similar issue with the Liferay DXP EE SP1 bundle. I had to restart my bundle for audience targeting to deploy properly the first time.

I also ran into an issue with not being able to add reports in campaigns. I found the following solution on the liferay forums that worked for me. You need the appropriate fixpack for Liferay DXP. If you have any issues with DXP with bundled HSQL, then you need to use MySQL or another database as HSQL is not supported

https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/87413363

Hope this helps.